# OpenVPN issue verifying CRL

Tags: openvpn, openssl, crl

With an OpenVPN/EasyRSA 3 setup (split machines for CA and VPN entry point), I'm facing the issue that whatever CRL I generate, OpenVPN seemingly cannot handle it.

### Setup Overview: Things That Go Well

I was following these guidelines to setup the respective machines:

- [OpenVPN server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-8)
- [CA server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-a-certificate-authority-ca-on-centos-8)

Everything regarding signing requests for clients, their actual signing, connecting to the VPN, nameserver pushes, private name resolution and such works very smoothly. However, I can revoke a certificate on the CA (as far as I know, there's no "revocation request" and instead certificates are directly revoked on the CA) and generate the according CRL like so:

```bash
./easyrsa revoke doe.john.client
./easyrsa gen-crl
```

The revocation works, the certificate is marked with an `R` on the `index.txt`; checking the generated CRL and comparing the certificate IDs also works, the IDs are correct.

```bash
openssl crl -noout -text -in <CRL-file>.pem
```

### Where Things Start to Fail

Now, the next step after generating the CRL is to transfer it to the OpenVPN server, change file permissions (`664`) and update OpenVPN's `server.conf` to use it:

```
[... properly working OpenVPN server.conf]

crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
```

After restarting the service via `systemctl` and attaching to the logs via `journalctl`, I start doing connection attempts for client certificates that should be **valid** and have **not** been revoked.

What I see on the logs then is the following:

```
TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]<IP-REDACTED>:52786, sid=e545b723 a0690e44
<IP-REDACTED>:52786 VERIFY WARNING: depth=0, unable to get certificate CRL: CN=<COMMON-NAME-OF-VALID-CLIENT>
<IP-REDACTED>:52786 VERIFY WARNING: depth=1, unable to get certificate CRL: CN=<COMMON-NAME-OF-CA>
<IP-REDACTED>:52786 VERIFY ERROR: CRL not loaded
<IP-REDACTED>:52786 OpenSSL: error:1417C086:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:certificate verify failed
<IP-REDACTED>:52786 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
<IP-REDACTED>:52786 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
<IP-REDACTED>:52786 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

which essentially tells me that

- the client is able to contact the VPN server
- the server is able to `stat` the `crl.pem` (otherwise the logs do tell that that step failed), i.e. file permissions are good
- the CRL has *not expired*
- using `openssl` directly to generate a CRL (without convenience functionality of EasyRSA) yields the same issues
- the server tries to check for a CRL on both depth levels, i.e. for the client certificate and the CA, which seems odd to me
- the logs state that the CRL is not loaded
- no client is able to connect anymore

### What Am I Missing?

I cannot seem to handle this issue, because neither the logs, nor whatever guidelines online or online searches seem to point towards similar issues. Dear experts, am I missing something around here?

If you need more details, I will happily provide them. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of back and forth, there now is a solution. I am not aware of any deeper details, but:

- My existing VPN entry server was still running on CentOS, which is already out of support for quite some months now.
- I just stumbled upon this on my update routines and obviously failed in updating the VPN entry server the past couple of runs, which is really bad.
- Now, I moved the setup to a Rocky Linux 9 and with unchanged CRL, server configs and their locations, the CRL now is loaded properly.

Key finding: **Make sure to not forget some servers when doing update routines - especially not the critical/important ones**

Comment: @jbnldr Maybe it is better to remove this question from Stack Overflow since the answer is not technical specific and does not help..

Comment: @jpoppe Mh, I also thought so, but if people run into the same issue because they're using outdated versions, they'll at least find this as a hint. I didn't find anything related online..